# Incorrect accuracy in SVM classification

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am trying to solve a classification problem. I am using SVM with a linear kernel inbuilt in opencv. I have extracted 2 features from images for training. The problem is when I used feature 1 alone for classification it gave me 71.825% accuracy on test set and the other gave 48.325% but when I used both the features combined both test and training accuracy is much less. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are your training and test sets disjoint? It might be the result of overfitting.

Comment: @MarkMiller Yes both the training and test set are disjoint.